# Foreach loops if problem

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to get a 0 result from this foreach loop but it just stays blank. However it does execute the else if part.

I just want to display entries from a database. If there is no entry I just want a plain 0.

```
$entries = array();


$sql = "SELECT   `id`   FROM   `events` where creator_id='$id'  ORDER BY  `id` DESC         
LIMIT 1";


 $query = mysql_query($sql);
 while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false)
 {
 $entries[] = $row['id'];
  }


$value1 = "0";
foreach($entries as $entry) 
{  
  if ($entry == false) 
   {
    echo "0";
   }      
  else 
 if($entry > $value1) 
  {
   echo "$entry";
   }
}
```

what might the problem be here?

Comment: Is **$entries** an array and what values it contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (count($entries) == 0)
    echo "0";
else foreach($entries as $entry)
{
    if($entry > $value1)
    {
        echo "$entry";
    }
}
```

Note that this may still display nothing if everything in $entry is <= $value1.  You may want to move that logic to your SQL statement, depending on exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

This might solve your problem.

use `!=` instead of `!==` in the while loop.

Comment: It won't. Check the manual, [`mysql-fetch-assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) returns FALSE

Comment: That means ["not identical"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).